# Android mobile apps retrieve data from cloud

Tags: android, url, mobile, cloud, uri

I wish to have an overview on this scenario. 
Please be layman term, I am slow learner.

Here is the scenario:

- Android mobile apps connect to the cloud, then the cloud will return a website link for me. eg. http://www.example.com/123
- Website link to be return can be control by admin on the cloud.
- Mobile apps will only request the link from cloud.
- The cloud there will only sending the link to the mobile apps when have request.

Problems:

1. What is cloud? what can be done on cloud?
2. How to connect the mobile apps to the cloud?
3. What need to be done on the cloud? host a server?
4. How the mobile apps connect to a website link? using uri will redirect me to the browser. i wish it can be just connected.

Thank you very much.. ^^

Comment: For this purpose you need a hosting server. This is free server i am using 2freehosting.com   create account on this site. Then create Database in there. You also need to create php file that provides url link that is saved in your Database and send to android device.

Answer (score 1):

> What is cloud?

In the simplest terms, cloud computing means storing and accessing data and programs over the Internet instead of your computer's hard drive. The cloud is just a metaphor for the Internet. In this case it refers to your server. Which you may need to purchase. (Server space + domain name[optional]).

> What can be done on cloud?

Accept some requests from the client and return some data.

> What need to be done on the cloud? Host a server?

The server has to be configured so that it can receive requests from the clients (mobile app). For this you need to install a Web server application like Apache, tomcat, ngnix, IIS, glassfish...etc (this depends on your server code). Also you need an application where you need to write the logic to handle the requests and return the response (In your case the website link). The application can be wriiten in PHP, Java, Python, javascript, .NET,..etc. The client communicates with this application.

> How to connect the mobile apps to the cloud?
>   How the mobile apps connect to a website link? using uri will redirect me to the browser. I wish it can be just connected.

Basically (on Android) you make a simple `URLConnection` to the server from your code. Or you can use some libraries like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). Make sure your app has `INTERNET` permission. These are a million (more maybe) tutorials on the internet that can tell you how.

Answer (score 1):

use free hosting or purchase hosting and try to learn about restFUL api..
try these tutorials

[Android Volley Post Request Tutorial – User Registration App](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/)

[Android Studio Volley Tutorial to Create a Login Application](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-studio-volley-tutorial-to-create-a-login-application/)